# Is "refactor" a real word

Tags: terminology

I am not sure if this question belongs here, but I can't get an answer from Google.

Basically I am trying to write a report on the refactor of an application. However, it appears the word "refactor" is actually not a word. The Oxford dictionary does not include this word. However in the programming community this word is universally used and accepted.

I'm trying to understand how can this be? Or from a grammatical point of view would "re-factor" be more appropriate?

Can anyone give me a definitive answer on if refactor (or refactoring) is a legitimate word to use?

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on the English SE site, or at least on Programming or SuperUser.

Comment: Unless reviewers of your report actually check if all words you use exist in a dictionary, I'd just say, don't waste too much time bothering yourself with that stuff.

Comment: I prefer Free Actor. I like actors!

Comment: Yes, it's legitimate if you're using it in the appropriate context. There's always context-dependent jargon, and it's not necessarily bad if your general audience can be expected to understand what you mean. Consider your audience: English professors or professional programmers. You said yourself in the question that is "universally used and accepted" in the programming community. So it may not be in Oxford yet, but it's made it's way into several "computer" dictionaries, and I predict it's only a matter of time until it, like so many words before it, gets accepted into the "real" dictionary.